# Unit test failed when multiple test classes not single class

Tags: c#, realm, xunit

I wrote some test cases in two classes, and run xunit, I got strange result that one of the class is all succeeded and another class is all failed.
I never met like this. I'm using Realm.NET, in test case, I setup Realm as new instance at constructor, I teardown calling Realm.DeleteRealm at Dispose.

I use Visual Studio 2019 preview (for new features), running on windows 10 pro, test target project uses .NET Core 3.0 preview, xunit 2.4.1, realm 4.1.0.
realm is used in test target, using xunit I want to test this target.
I have some question in myself, realm can use on windows correctly?, preview version is ok?, setup and teardown is right?, etc..

I tried all cases move to one class, then all cases succeeded.
More I tried all cases do nothing, then I got absolutely same result.

as two classes;

```
class One
{
    [Fact]
    public void Case1() { /* do nothing */ }
    public void Case2() { /* do nothing */ }
    public void Case3() { /* do nothing */ }
}
class Two
{
    public void Case4() { /* do nothing */ }
    public void Case5() { /* do nothing */ }
}
```

as one class;

```
class Gather
{
    public void Case1() { /* do nothing */ }
    public void Case2() { /* do nothing */ }
    public void Case3() { /* do nothing */ }
    public void Case4() { /* do nothing */ }
    public void Case5() { /* do nothing */ }
}
```

At failed case I got this error;

> System.IO.IOException : The process cannot access the file '{realm
>   file path}' because it is being used by another process.

What process is using?
I think xunit creates new instance and dispose every time, I don't set it parallel, so there is no process touching realm file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default XUnit test runner executes tests from different classes in parallel. https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html
If you are using same file for both classes, only first class who open the file will be able to use a file.

As workaround you can group both test classes into one test collection.

```
[Collection("Realm tests")]
public class One
{

}

[Collection("Realm tests")]
public class Two
{

}
```

"Run tests in isolation" - mean every test should be independent from other tests.

File system introduces global state of application under the test and will couple different tests together.

Actual solution would be to "mock" a file, I am not familiar with Realm, but if there a chance to provide required data without touching a file system, I would recommend to do it, then tests will be isolated from each other and can be executed and maintained in more efficient manner.

Comment: Very Thanks! I was not conscious of collection, I got it! I have to study more about xUnit...

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!